# How to make marquee text pop up again immediately after it leaves the screen view in Android

Tags: android, textview

I have been trying to move the marquee text from right to left in Android, using ellipsize.

It does move, but the issue is it moves only if the text size is smaller than screen view.

For that reason, I even added extra spaces both left and right of my text, to make the text size greater than screen size. Now after the text scrolls out of the screen, there is a small delay before it could come again from the right end of the screen.

I want it to come up immediately, as soon as the text goes out of the screen.

Following is the customized Ticker I have created for the marquee.

```
public class Ticker extends AppCompatTextView {

    public Ticker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setSelected(true);
        setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
        setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        setFreezesText(true);
        setSingleLine(true);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    }
}
```

and the text is "\t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t sometext \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a textview in your layout file.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMarquee"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="0.50dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/bg_login"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Write below code in your MainActivity in OnCreate method.

```
TextView txtMarquee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMarquee);
Animation marquee = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.marquee);
txtMarquee.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,0);
txtMarquee.startAnimation(marquee);
txtMarquee.setText("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieve this in different way as below:

Add this to your layout activity.xml

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/marque_scrolling_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

And add below code in MainActivity class inside onCreate method:

```
        TextView marque = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.marque_scrolling_text);
        marque.setText("This is Scrolling Text in Android Using TextView.");
        marque.setText(scrolltext);
        marque.setSelected(true);
        marque.setSingleLine(true);
```